# iphone sdk how to add option in UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using UIwebview .In webview if you longpress on the screen it will show copy,paste popup.I want to add one more option (custom) into that popUp.How to add that and how to handle that.Can any one share the code please.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by handling touch events of your `window` and also you need to use some `javascript` functions to Contextual menu in `UIWebView`. For more about this follow the tutorial - http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/07/11/customize-the-contextual-menu-of-uiwebview/